# how to store all checkbox values in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

i m trying to store checkbox values inside variable `$days` but when i store this value to database it just store the last selected checkbox inside the database... please help me to sort out the code so i can get all selected values

```
    <?php

   if (isset($_POST['days'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['days'] as $day) {
        $days = " " . $day;
    }
} else {
    $days = "not available";
}  
?>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
<td>Select Days :</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Sunday">Sunday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Monday">Monday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Thursday">Thursday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Friday">Friday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Saturday">Saturday
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="All Days">All Days
</td>
<td></td>
```

Comment: use `$days .= " " . $day;`

Comment: thnx for the help :) ..... one dot(.) can make a difference lolzz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign a normal string to `$days` and overwrite it on each iteration. You could *append* to it, by using the `.=` operator. (`$days .= ' ' . $day`), but maybe easier is to use `implode`:

```
if (isset($_POST['days'])) {
  $days = implode(' ', $_POST['days']);
} else {
  $days = "not available";
}
```

Note there is a small functional difference. `implode` will add spaces inbetween the days, while the foreach loop will also put a space at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `$days` with each iteration of the forech loop. Instead you want to add to it. Most likely this is what you are looking for:

```
if (isset($_POST['days'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['days'] as $day) {
        $days .= " " . $day;
    }
} else {
    $days = "not available";
}
```

If so, then you can even simplify the code and remove the loop:

```
if (isset($_POST['days'])) {
    $days = implode(" ", $_POST['days']);
} else {
    $days = "not available";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` to concatate the string

```
$days .= " " . $day;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make $days as array and then push the values you get from checkbox into array.

```
$days[] = $day
```

inside your foreach statement